# .dockerignore not ignoring docker-compose.yml

Tags: node.js, github, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, dockerignore

I've been reading through the posts here and all over, but still I don't get why my docker-compose files are not being ignored.

They are at my projects root directory. Along with my `.env`, `package.json` and everything else.

So, here is my `.dockerignore` file:

```
.git
docker*
docker-compose.yml
node_modules
.env
*.log
.gitignore
yarn.log
.dockerignore
.editorconfig
README.md
LICENSE
.vscode
```

I have tried different things, such as: `docker-compose.yml*` , `*docker-compose.yml` and `*docker-compose`

Still I get this file pushed over to the remote branch.

Any different approaches?

Comment: _Still I get this file pushed over to the remote branch._ > Are you sure you are not confusing _.dockerignore_ and _.gitignore_?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure. I tried adding it to .gitignore as well. To no avail.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem Restated:

It appears that you're getting `.gitignore` confused with `.dockerignore`:

[The later file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) tells Docker what files to ignore during the ***build of a Docker image***. `.dockerignore` has nothing to do with Git pushes to upstream branches.

### Solution:

Add the `docker-compose.yml` file(s) to your `.gitignore` file if you don't want Git tracking the file(s).

Don't delete `.dockerignore` if you want it read during builds.

Answer (score 0):

If by "Still I get this file pushed over to the remote branch", you mean you are trying to gitignore that file then you can remove it using

`git rm --cached docker-composer.yml`

Comment: I have tried applying the above command and adding compose to .gitignore. No success. I'm working around this by simply removing docker-cmpose from the repos.